# Visual Studio 2008 - syntax-highlighting and intellisense not working for aspx, js, css

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, syntax-highlighting

I'm having problems with Visual Studio 2008, namely, syntax-highlighting and intellisense for *.aspx, *.js and *.css files (and maybe more) not working. Also, when I go to Tools -> Options... -> Text editor -> HTML -> Format, I see this error message:

"An error occurred loading this property page"

Everything was working fine before, until recently.

The only change that might have possibly triggered this (but I am not 100% sure whether it stopped working at that exact time or some other time) was a change of the display language in my Windows 7 installation.

I have already tried running:

devenv /Setup
devenv /ResetSkipPkgs
devenv /ResetSettings

...none of which helped. Also, setting my default system font to Tahoma, which was a suggestion I found somewhere else, did not work for me (it was Tahoma before, since I use the Windows Classic theme).

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried setting the display language back to it's original value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. The problem was caused by a great Visual Studio add-on called DPack, which I installed a beta version of. After uninstalling the beta and installing the final release, everything went back to normal.